# How to set reward function when using Reinforcement Learning in path searching problems?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

i created a environment with a tiny random influence and without any obstacle, that an agent can move around to find ways from start point to destination. first i use ϵ -greedy Policies to load 20000 ways as samples to train a NN, then i wish that my NN could creat ways independently from start point to destination. but somehow it never worked, the NN cannot reach to the destination no matter how many times i tried.

i thought it might be the problem with the reward function, so i use 2 different reward function:

1. r=-1(not arriving)/r=100(arriving)
2. r=exp(-dis_now/dis_all)
   but still not working, can anyone plz give me some precious advice?
   and i'll read more papers at the same time ofc.
   thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

okay so I've found a perfect reward function that actually solved my problem, which is:
r = 1/dis_now
this is a simple but effective one, because it provides strong award when getting close to the destination, and when get to the setted radius from the destination, the agent will stop and end the round, so i dont need to worry about rewards may gone too big.